# Get next element with after each element matching a specific class name

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, element

**Set-up**

I have the following html table,

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="order-activ_order_delivered">
        <tr class="tracking-url tracking-url-activ_order_delivered">
        <tr class="order-activ_order_delivered">
        <tr class="tracking-url tracking-url-activ_order_delivered">
        <tr class="order-activ_order_delivered">
        <tr class="tracking-url tracking-url-activ_order_delivered">
        <tr class="order-complete">
        <tr class="empty-tracking-url order-complete">
        <tr class="order-activ_order_delivered">
        <tr class="tracking-url tracking-url-activ_order_delivered">
        <tr class="order-activ_order_delivered">
        <tr class="tracking-url tracking-url-activ_order_delivered">
        <tr class="order-complete">
        <tr class="empty-tracking-url order-complete">
    <tbody>
</table>
```

I need ONLY the information in the rows with class names `"order-activ_order_delivered"` and `"tracking-url tracking-url-activ_order_delivered"`.

Moreover, the information of any `"order-activ_order_delivered"` row is related with the subsequent `"tracking-url tracking-url-activ_order_delivered"` row.

---

**Code so far**

The following loop gets each `"order-activ_order_delivered"`,

```
order_table = el_css(browser,'#my-orders-table > tbody')

for order in order_table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                           "tr[class^='order-activ_order_delivered']"):
    #code to get data from row
```

---

**Question**

To get the information of the subsequent `"tracking-url tracking-url-activ_order_delivered"` row I tried,

```
for order in order_table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                           "tr[class^='order-activ_order_delivered']"):
    
    order_table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                           "tr[class^='order-activ_order_delivered']/following-sibling::tr")
```

but this gives an  `InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.127)`

Either because you can't use `following-sibling` on a `CSS_SELECTOR` or because something else.

How do I get the from the subsequent `"tracking-url tracking-url-activ_order_delivered"` row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`following-sibling` is not `CSS_Selector` syntax it is `xpath` syntax.

Your code should be like identify the specific element and then using `xpath` to check the `following-sibling`

```
 for order in order_table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                           "tr[class^='order-activ_order_delivered']"):

      nextelement=order.find_element(By.XPATH, "./following-sibling::tr[@class='tracking-url tracking-url-activ_order_delivered']")
```

Or

```
for order in order_table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                               "tr[class^='order-activ_order_delivered']"):
    
          nextelement=order.find_element(By.XPATH, "./following-sibling::tr[1]")
```

---

In case of want to use `css selector` use can use this which will return all tracking-url.

```
tr[class^='order-activ_order_delivered']+tr.tracking-url.tracking-url-activ_order_delivered
```

Code:

```
for order in order_table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                           "tr[class^='order-activ_order_delivered']+tr.tracking-url.tracking-url-activ_order_delivered"):
    nextelement=order
```